# Change "-" to "C" in all files within directory

Tags: bash

I have some files that looks like this:

```
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH--HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH------HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH-----HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH-
d2qupa_.dssp (END)
```

And I would like to change all those with "-" to "C"

This is a file in a directory of 150 files that are similar, so I need a code that applies to every files.

I tried this:

```
for f in *.dssp; do mv -- "$f" "${f//"-"/"C"}"; done
```

It does not work at all, no error, even though its clearly parsing the files.

Is it because it is a directory that its not opening the file itself and applying the loop?

Comment: why the `python` tag?

Comment: Well, if someone wants to offer a python script for this they can...

Comment: The *name* of the file is `---HHH...`, or does the file *contain* `---HHH...`? If the latter, you want something like `sed`, not `mv`.

Comment: @chepner the latter, it is what the file contains, ah okay, I tried it...but it is saying "extra characters at the end of d command"

Comment: Tried *what*? You definitely don't want to use `sed`'s `d` command, which *deletes* lines.

Comment: _if someone wants to offer a python script for this they can_ - well, Stack Overflow is NOT free code writing service.

Comment: @buran I would if I could, if its quick and easy enough, which this is! I thought people can come here to ask anything they wish if they are stuck? its nice to compare everyones codes and ideas too, everyone learns new ways of doing things even if they are pros

Comment: @chepner Ok I tried this: 
for f in *.dssp; do sed 's/-/C/g' ; done
it just leaves the command line hanging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are conflating the file *name* with the file *contents*

This:

```
for f in *.dssp; do mv -- "$f" "${f//"-"/"C"}"; done
```

seems to be using `mv` which is trying to rename the file. Instead, you example is addressing the file contents.

To change the contents as in your example, you only need `sed`.

Given:

```
$ head *.dssp
==> f1.dssp <==
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH--HHHHHHHHH--HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH------HHHHHHH--HHHHHHHHHHHHHH-----HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH-
d2qupa_.dssp (END)

==> f2.dssp <==
---HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH--HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH------HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH-----HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH-
d2qupa_.dssp (END)
```

You can use `sed` to modify all files in place (the original files are saved with `.old` extension):

```
$ sed -i .old 's/-/C/g' *.dssp

$ head *.dssp
==> f1.dssp <==
CCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCHHHHHHHHHCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCCCCHHHHHHHCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHC
d2qupa_.dssp (END)

==> f2.dssp <==
CCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHCCCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHC
d2qupa_.dssp (END)
```

---

From your comment above:

*I tried this:* `for f in *.dssp; do sed 's/-/C/g' ; done` *it just leaves the command line hanging* -- That is because `sed` is waiting for a file in that shell loop. There is no file name argument to `sed`.

You would do `for f in *.dssp; do sed -i .bak 's/-/C/g'  "$f"; done` if you want the shell to handle the glob. BUT, `sed` itself can handle the glob. You would want to use the shell if additional processing is required to each file. Otherwise just use `sed`.

Comment: Okay let me see... this should work on the files that are in the directory?

Comment: Yes. `sed` can handle globs just like the shell can.

Comment: Wow, what a beautiful line of code! love that is just saves the old files in the same directory...thank you!